# Electron Degeneracy and Specific Locations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I was reading about stars collapse towards a neutron star and it raised a question...

I understand the electron cloud is more a general area where electrons are and they are not really discrete points within the cloud.  However as the stellar matter falls in on itself; at the moment of the greatest electron degeneracy pressure, does the electron cloud condense so small that it forces the electrons into discrete points?  Or is the cloud simply smashed into the nucleus without ever becoming discrete electrons?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Atoms don't exist in degenerate stars; just nuclei and essentially free electrons.

Comment: I am talking about the transition time between regular matter and degenerate matter.  As the atoms are crushed together by gravity and at the point of greatest electron degeneracy pressure....  Think of the point between the size of a white dwarf to the size neutron star.

Comment: There are no atoms in a white dwarf either.

Comment: Ok - I am confused now.  I have always read that the WD star has a core of solid O2 and Carbon.  That it is kept from collapsing further by electron degeneracy pressure.  How is degenerate matter different from normal matter?

Comment: There are simply nuclei and effectively free electrons.

Comment: So are the electrons discrete particles are are they still in a cloud?